# show the country name by passing the array index in laravel view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I store user country in my user table, country field as an integer number.

and i have a php function contain world countries in an indexed array, i would like to know how can i create an helper or something like that in Laravel, so i can show the country name in my view by passing the value that i get from my database ( country field ) to the country function

my function code example :

```
function country($table_value){
   $country = array('USA','CANADA','France');
    return $country[$table_value];
}
```

How can i use this function in my Laravel Views, like that for example

```
{{ country($user-country) }}
```

or you can suggest me another solution

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply create a Helper function and call from view like that:

```
{{ \Helper::country($user->country) }}
```

If you don't know how to create custom helper function in laravel then you can see [this](https://laravel-news.com/creating-helpers) blog.